# Java compiler gives "file not found" error

Tags: java, graphics, compiler-errors, applet

```
javac: file not found: C:\applet.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

Process completed.
```

//APPLET CODE BELOW (not html run file)//

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class applet
{
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawRect(100, 100, 80, 80);
    }
}
```

Comment: EDIT: I set the path to the jdk as well so non graphics programs work.

Comment: Is this a problem with configuring file paths and project file paths? Or is it a problem with the HTML?

Comment: What main method? What applet?  What command line do you use to compile the class?

Comment: First of all the class applet doesn't extend anything, second, there is no main method, third, what compiler are you compiling with, forth, GIVE US MORE INFO :/ we are not mind readers

Comment: What part of `file not found: C:\applet.java` don't you understand? And why would you put Java source files in the root directory anyway?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you've saved the applet's source code (file `applet.java`) in a different place/path than where you're trying to compile it (path `C:\applet.java`). That's why `javac` cannot find your source code.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was just a simple mistake. I am new to stack and programming, so I was not sure what all to include in my answer. I appreciate your help. @Christian Hujer